# How do I get the ID of a role?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to get a channel permissions overwrite. I need an ID of a role which is stored in a variable. How would I get the ID of this new role? I've been stuck on this for days.

I've tried the following:

```
const guild = client.guilds.get("server_id_here");
const role = guild.roles.find("name", `${name}`); // This gets the role I need
// Further down a bit to where the ID is required:
channel.permissionOverwrites({
  overwrites: [{
    id: role.id,
    allowed: ['CONNECT', 'VIEW_CHANNEL'],
  }],
  reason: 'Updating so the channel is private'
});
```

I've tried other things such as `guild.role.id` or `role.id` and they are not working either.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=id

Comment: Or this ? https://anidiots.guide/understanding/roles

Comment: That is the thing, The role is being created within this command, So that is why I need the role ID stored for the channel permission updates. And looking at what @KoenHollander sent, i dont know how I'd put that into the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

`array.prototype.find('name', 'name')` is deprecated and often isn't very efficient. You may want to try something like `let role = guild.roles.find(r => r.name === 'rolename')` then using that variable you can said `id: role.id`, were you to have provided a valid role.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me though. As it says: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null`

And also when logging the variable role, it came back as a lot of things.

Comment: Did you replace 'rolename' with the name of the role?